# Improving how autocomplete works for img tag in React

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, tags, code-snippets

I am learning to use React and using Visual Studio Code.
When I insert an image I write: .
I installed the extension: ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Nativesnippets and it's working with for example RFCE.

1. Is it possible to add an autocomplete? So for example I just need to enter img and then press control + something that it is autocompleting the whole tag? Or that a menu pops up where I can choose what I want to enter? I tried entering "img" and pressed control + space but it says "no suggestions".
2. Is it possible to add suggestions to the ctrl + space option?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can get some intellisense.  You need to ensure the files have the correct extension and that you have installed the correct extensions.  I suggest this one:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jawandarajbir.react-vscode-extension-pack